# Java enum in class: make fields inaccessible & methods accessible

Tags: java, enums

I have a User class with an enum in it:

```java
public class User
{
    private int index;
    private enum Counter
    {
        INSTANCE;
        private int objects;

        protected int getObjects()
        {
            return objects;
        }

        protected void setObjects()
        {
            this.objects++;
        }
    }

    public User(){
        this.index = User.Counter.INSTANCE.getObjects();
        User.Counter.INSTANCE.setObjects();
    }
}
```

In this class I am still able to do

```java
this.index = User.Counter.INSTANCE.objects; //in public User()
```

How can I make it so that this line becomes invalid?

Comment: _Invalid_ how? What part of it should fail? The access to `objects`?Why do you want this? Any `private` member can be accessed in any part of the outermost enclosing class.

Comment: I don't want the class User to be able to access the field, but only the methods.
So you say it is not possible to do that?

Comment: Not with `Counter` declared within `User`.

Comment: so I should just declare it outside the User class? If I do, how can I make the enum only accessible to the User class and no other classes?

Comment: You can't. But you shouldn't care about that. Just declare it within `User` and forget about hiding `objects`. Just don't access it anywhere outside the enum type body. Document that it shouldn't be accessed directly.